# How to use IGxDialog to save output feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I found this code to take input through IGxDialog box from a guidebook:

```c#
IGxDialog gxd = new GxDialogClass();
gxd.AllowMultiSelect = false;
gxd.ButtonCaption = "Add FileGDB";
gxd.Title = "Add All FeatureClasses inside FileGDB";
gxd.RememberLocation = true;
IGxObjectFilter gxObjFilter = new GxFilterFileGeodatabasesClass();
gxd.ObjectFilter = gxObjFilter;
IEnumGxObject gxEnumObj;
gxd.DoModalOpen(ArcMap.Application.hWnd, out gxEnumObj);
IGxObject gxObj = gxEnumObj.Next();
//getting the address of fileGDB
string fileGDBAddress = gxObj.FullName;
```

I could not figure how save a feature class through IGxDialog Box, there are no examples on internet with arcobject 10.0

Comment: An IGXDialog interface has the method `DoModalSave` have a look at the API help for that.

Comment: is there any illustrative example available for how to use DoModalSave

Comment: Anything code related and you should be looking at GeoNet, here is a [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/message/356829?commentID=356829#comment-356829) from 4 years ago!

Comment: i read the link and found the code in vb.net tried to covert it to c# but stuck on .DoModalSave(Me.Handle.ToInt32)   , coz c# does have handles.

Comment: Just use a zero?